# Delete subscriber from mailchimp using asp.net wrappper

Tags: asp.net, mailchimp

How can I delete subscriber from mailchimp list using the asp.net API, actually i found that it is possible to add subscriber through the API it is gonna be so weird that I can't delete subscriber!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest API (1.3) you can delete a subscriber from the list using:

```
// Unsubscribe the given email address from the list 
listUnsubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, boolean delete_member,
     boolean send_goodbye, boolean send_notify)
```

See [MailChimp API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/#listrelated).